# How to initialize inline the ControlCollection Controls property of a Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, initialization

It really bugs me that I can't do this

```
    Panel panel = new Panel()
    {
        Controls = new ControlCollection(this)
        {
            new Panel()
            {
                Controls = new ControlCollection(this)
                {
                    new Label() { Text = "Label1" },
                    new Label() { Text = "Label2" }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Because, in this particular case I get `Property or indexer 'Control.Controls' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`.

And instead I have to do this

```
    Panel innerPanel = new Panel();
    innerPanel.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Label1" });
    innerPanel.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Label2" });
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    panel.Controls.Add(innerPanel);
```

Any clever ways to get the tree like code style to work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply omit the `ControlCollection` constructor calls:

```
Panel panel = new Panel
{
    Controls =
    {
        new Panel
        {
            Controls =
            {
                new Label { Text = "Label1" },
                new Label { Text = "Label2" }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This will add the `Panel` and `Label` child controls to the *existing* `ControlCollection` objects returned by the `Controls` properties, instead of creating new `ControlCollection` objects.

Comment: Awesome that it works like that. The error is kinda misleading